# Error in Flask Web App in Python: pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: Cursor closed

Tags: python, database, flask, web-applications

I can't seem to figure out the error that I'm getting "pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: Cursor closed" in my flask web application. I'm sure I'm making a trivial mistake, but there is not much documentation on this error. The error is occurring on the line "cursor.execute(query, email)". The following is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pymysql.cursors
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
IMAGES_DIR = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "images")

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                       port=8889,
                       user='LandingPage',
                       password='t9ybKLtVaS6qLQ7g',
                       db='LandingPage',
                       charset='utf8mb4',
                       cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.form:
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        phone_number = request.form['phone number']

        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            query = 'SELECT * FROM LandingPage WHERE email = %s'
            cursor.execute(query, email)
            data = cursor.fetchone()
            conn.commit()
        error = None
        if data:
            error = "A person with this email already exists in the database"
            return render_template('home.html', error=error)
        else:
            ins = "INSERT INTO LandingPage (name, email, phone number) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(ins, (name, email, phone_number))
            conn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            return render_template('home.html')
    return render_template('home.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('127.0.0.1', 4999, debug=True)
```

Comment: what line is the error coming from?

Comment: @Sam sorry I should have clarified - the home page of this works on localhost:4999/home, but as soon as I submit the form after I typed in name, email, and phone number, I am redirected back to localhost:4999/home and that is where I receive this error. It is on line "cursor.execute(query, email)"

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is a result of trying to use the object after it has already been closed. Most objects that employ the `with` keyword do so to control access to some underlying resource. In this case, it is the cursor for the database connection. When you use the `with` keyword, Python will execute a specific method before the execution of the interior block of code, and execute a specific method when that block of code finishes. This allows code using the `with` keyword to control things like opening and closing of a file. When your code exits the `with` block, it calls the `close()` method of the cursor object, which kills the data connection to the database. After that point, you continue to use the cursor object and so it gives you that error.

To resolve this issue, every interaction that involves the cursor should be indented into the code block defined with `with`.

See below:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.form:
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        phone_number = request.form['phone number']

        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            query = 'SELECT * FROM LandingPage WHERE email = %s'
            cursor.execute(query, email)
            data = cursor.fetchone()
            conn.commit()
            error = None # new indentation starts at this line
            if data:
                error = "A person with this email already exists in the database"
                return render_template('home.html', error=error)
            else:
                ins = "INSERT INTO LandingPage (name, email, phone number) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
                cursor.execute(ins, (name, email, phone_number))

        conn.commit()
        # cursor.close() # this line is redundant
        return render_template('home.html')
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Comment: This is a super concise and clear answer, I understand now completely. Thank you so much!